# VueJS bind style with class selector

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to implement something very simple here, something in CSS:

```
.p {
    color: /*something from javascript logic*/;
}
```

By checking the VueJS document, there is one way to achieve this by [Style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html):

```
<p :style="{color:/*something from javascript*/}"> ... </p>
```

However, to do so, it means that I need to add every p tag such line, and it's not really a good solution.

What I want, is just like the beginning of the question, write something like

```
.p {
    color: {{mycolor}};
}
```

So that I can do it once, apply everywhere.

Is there a neat way to do this? Namely apply a class selector in VueJS style binding? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way of doing it in Vue.

There's a workaround/solution, though, which is just a custom component (say `<v-style>` or whatever you choose to name it), so it's as reusable as any other component, and all of Vue's goods -- like `v-if` -- can be used on its tag. Here's how it'd look:

```js
Vue.component('v-style', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement('style', this.$slots.default)
  }
});


// demo usage, check the template
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myColor: 'red'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app" class="stuff">
  <v-style>
    .p {
      color: {{myColor}};
    }
  </v-style>

  <div class="p">
  Remove "red" and type "yellow":
  <input class="setting" type="text" v-model="myColor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Caveats: the styles generated will be there **only as long as the component is**!

Another minor drawback is that since the name of the tag is `<v-style>` (or whatever you chose to call it) and not `<style>`, the IDEs may not color it nicely. But otherwise it'll just be like a regular `<style>` tag.

Comment: why wouldn't you make your custom component accept the color as props?

Comment: @Michael no specific reason, really. It is pretty much doable (the props). In the example I gave, the goal is to have a "templateable" style tag, not just a parameterized color style. But I see your point. If that's what the OP needs, it is quite simple to add the props to the `v-style` or even a simpler component (without the default slots functionality).

Comment: @Michael I think did the right thing because the question here is really a much simpler version of what I'm actually dealing with so I would appreciate the answer to be as generic as possible.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, I made it as the accepted answer, but if someone knows a package that does this for us (or even more powerful), please suggest it. As it might make the code easier to develop as other people working on the code can easily understand it by checking the docs of the certain package instead of trying to figure out how the <v-style> works.